# Показать содержимое файла в другом классе

Tags: ios, swift, файлы, классы, global-variables

Есть  метод для считывания информации с файл и глобальная перменная.

```
var content:String

class readFile
{
    func getDataFromFile(name: String , type:String)
    {   
        let pathFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: type)
        let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: pathFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        let  randomContent = contentString.components(separatedBy: ["#"]).randomElement()!//.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
        content = randomContent

    }
}
```

Я создал глобальную переменную `content` чтобы помещать туда контет из файла и показывать в другом классе при вызове этот метода. Сейчас это дело выдглядит так.

```
class someClass:UIViewController
{
   @IBOutlet weak var textLabel:UILabel!

  let readFile = readFile()

  func getData()
{
   readFile.getDataFromFile(name:"someName",type:"txt")

    textLabel.text = content
 }

}
```

Но этот как то по 'кривому'. Подскажите как можно усовершенствовать например метод `getDataFromFile`, чтобы обойтись без глобальных переменных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что мешает сделать так

```
class readFile
{
    func getDataFromFile(name: String , type:String) -> String
    {   
        let pathFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: type)
        let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: pathFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        return contentString.components(separatedBy: ["#"]).randomElement()!//.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
    }
}
```

И затем

```
textLabel.text = readFile().getDataFromFile(name:"someName",type:"txt")
```

Кстати имена типов (в тч классов) в Swift именуются с большой буквы и зачастую прибавляется название родительского типа для удобства и ясности, например `SomeViewController`

Также классам как правило даются описательные названия, например не `readFile` (это больше имя для функции), а например `FileReader`

Comment: Это мне помогло, спасибо.